# Input value not displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a multiphase form which has 3 steps. In first step you can choose a gender, in second step you can choose your age and the final step display the gender which you have choose and also the age.

The problem is that when I choose, for example, 'man' for gender, at the final step, it doesn't display the value of gender as man (value = "m") but instead displays it as women (value ="w").

How can I resolve this problem?

> Partial code HTML

```
<h3 id="status">Phase 1 of 2</h3>
<form id="multiphase" onsubmit="return false">
  <div id="phase1">
    <div>
      <label>
        <input id="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="w" />
        <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/rcons-user/32/female-shadow-circle-512.png" width="180px" height="180px"> 
      </label>
      <label>
        <input id="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="m"/>
        <img src="http://www.interport.sk/sites/default/files/inline-images/riaditel-spolocnosti_2.png" width="180px" height="180px">
      </label>
    </div>
    <button onclick="processPhase1()">Continue</button>
  </div>
    <div id="phase2">
      <div>
        <select id="age" name="age">
          <option>Choose your age</option>
          <option>18</option>
          <option>19</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <button onclick="processPhase2()" class="button-phase2">Continue</button>
    </div>
    <div id="show_all_data">
      Gender: <span id="display_gender"></span> <br>
      Age: <span id="display_age"></span> <br>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `id` of element in `document` should be unique.

Comment: i not understand, sorry can u please modify my code and link so i can see what is the problem. Thank you

Comment: @guest271314 can u please modify my code and link so i can see what is the problem. Thank you

Comment: on your radio buttons (gender part), you can't have multiple item with the same id.. try to make it like `gender_m` or `gender_w` to differentiate and use those id to check in the js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute `class="gender"` for `id="gender"`. `id` of element in `document` should be unique.

Use `document.querySelector()` with selector `".gender:checked"` at `processPhase1` function

```
<div id="phase1">
  <div>
    <label>
      <input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="w" />
      <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/rcons-user/32/female-shadow-circle-512.png" width="180px" height="180px">
    </label>

    <label>
      <input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="m" />
      <img src="http://www.interport.sk/sites/default/files/inline-images/riaditel-spolocnosti_2.png" width="180px" height="180px">
    </label>

  </div>
  <button onclick="processPhase1()">Continue</button>
```

```
  gender = document.querySelector(".gender:checked").value;
```

codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ObYrEO

Comment: @utente Note, `gender` variable and `if` condition could be adjusted to `gender = document.querySelector(".gender:checked");
 if(gender){` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GNaPBE?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

this is because you have given the same id attribute to your radio buttons for gender and you are trying to get the value using the ID. For radio button which are a group you can get the checked radio button by the group name

Change

```
<input id="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="w" />
<input id="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="m"/>
```

To something like

```
<input id="genderw" type="radio" name="gender" value="w" />
<input id="genderm" type="radio" name="gender" value="m"/>
```

and get the value of gender in the script like below.

```
gender = document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value;
```

Code pen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqGLyO